# A few questions about Handlebars. ie if statements, looping

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, handlebars.js

1.
How to do a "{{#if name == other_name}}" using Handlebars?

I am checking around and reading the docs, I do not see any example of how to do the if statement. Does Handlebars not support this?

2.
I need to create a "zebra" style table, where I set the class of a TD to "odd" or "even", how can I use some sort of variable inside the loop to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this post here answers both of your questions:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers